# Is there any online place where I can derive the plots of various fractional power functions like {nx}, {x^2}?

Tags: analytic-geometry, special-functions, graphing-functions, fractional-part

I've tried Wolfram and others but they don't understand the fractional part notation.

I've also tried writing it as a combination of a polynomial function and floor function but that too doesn't works.

Comment: @what do you mean derive the plot? Could you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: [x^2-floor(x^2)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+-+floor(x%5E2)).

Comment: Wolfram supports fractional part:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalPart.html.
But how do you define $\{x\}?$ Is it the fractional part or the fractional part mod 1, e.g. $\{-1.75\}=-0.75\,$ or $\{-1.75\}=0.25?$